# How are solana transactions indexed?

Tags: transactions, signature

Transactions are indexed by their signature. However, some transactions can have multiple signers. How is this handled to form one constant length "signature"? Are the different signatures hashed together? Is the signature at index 0 picked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer - it's always the signature produced by the signer at index 0.